# ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/tmp/file1.csv' (Errcode: 2) while trying to import CSV file into MariaDB

Tags: mysql, import, mariadb

I am trying to import CSV file into MariaDB (version: 5.5.50-MariaDB MariaDB Server), using this command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file1.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES  (@dummy,col1, col2,col3,@dummy) 
SET col4 = "xyz";
```

I am getting error as:

> ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/db_name/file1.csv' (Errcode: 2)

I also tried using LOCAL keyword as per some suggestions on stackoverflow and google search in the above query like:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file1.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES  (@dummy,col1, col2,col3,@dummy) 
SET col4 = "xyz";
```

in that case, I get a file not found error:

> ERROR 2 (HY000): File 'file1.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)

I have tried moving my source file to /tmp, /root and /var/lib/mysql/db_name directories but am not able to import using any of the above queries.

Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rename the file?  Perhaps its name is not as it appears due to one or more of the characters being a similar looking symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be either owned by "mysql", or readable by by "mysql".  Do `ls -l file1.csv` if you need further interpretation.

Also, check the value of `local_infile`.